# node express custom module object assignment issue

Tags: javascript, express

Created custom module which is getting data from mysql and it is working fine.
but when I assigned result data to some object variable then it is empty !
Here is my code full code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost",
user: "root",
password: "",
database: "test",
});

con.connect(function(err) {
if (err) throw err;
 console.log("local module connected !");
});    

module.exports = {       
    apple: () =>  {
      console.log("---------------------------------");
      var cars= {};
      con.query("SELECT * FROM test", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log( "Inside con.query : Type is : " + typeof result );  
        cars = result;            
      });

      // return resultsdata;
      console.log( "Type is : " + typeof cars );
      console.dir(  cars );
      console.log("---------------------------------");
    }
};
```

after

`cars = result;`

it is suppose to display all assigned object
But it is displaying empty/null.
Any suggestions or help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Because the result of the query execution is available after the callback function executes. And callback functions are asynchronous in nature.

So, the line `var cars= {};` gets executed and assigns `cars` as an empty object. Then the line `con.query...` is executed with a callback function and the execution continues to next lines, which are your `console.logs`. Since the callback function may not have finished yet, `cars = result;` is not yet executed.

If you can move the `console.log` statements in the callback function just after `cars = result;` statement, you will see the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I know it will console the result but the point is I need to use results in view so that is why I am assigning results to some variable .